# Image disappears when I try to change its size

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change an image's size using Javascript:

```
var theimage = document.getElementById('myimage');
theimage.height /= 2;
```

When I add this code, the image disappears. I've even tried this and it still disappears:

```
var theimage = document.getElementById('myimage');
theimage.height *= 1;
```

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: Seems to work for me. Can you post more code?

Comment: My advice... provide more context. Is this a big project you are working on or a few lines of code? If its a project, maybe paste these few lines of code into a separate javascript file and see if it works on it's own. That way you know the problem is with that code specifically and not some css or a previous line of code. Generally it is very hard to answer a question with only 4 lines of code.